# TeeChart For MonoDroid

Tags: xamarin.android, teechart

I downloaded the beta version of TeeChart for monodroid and tried to run the demos, but could't get any of them working, always get exception about invalid String or something. I did download their updated dll file...anybody could successfully ran their demos? thanks

Comment: It would help a lot of you included stack traces and the exact errors you get.

Comment: For demo MonodroidTabDemo, i got the exception saying System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime from Activity1.cs. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug. An assembly with the fix is available [here](http://tinyurl.com/c8ey5zk). Can you please try replacing your current TeeChart.Monodroid.dll with this one and try again?

Comment: this works! thanks very much, it's really a cool chart, when will you release the final product for monodroid?

Comment: @user1467537 you're welcome. Thanks for the feedback! We are working on improving a couple of important issues regarding memory consumption and rendering time before the final version comes out. We'd like it to be as soon as possible. Please stay tuned to our website for news updates.

Comment: @user1467537 As an update, a new beta has been posted: http://www.steema.com/entry/116/TeeChart_.NET_Mono_for_Android_Library_BETA_update the final version will follow up.